# How to reuse alias column in a mysql view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a `mysql` for with a column that references another column that is created within the view.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT '30' AS age, age AS person_age;
```

This does not work. Is it impossible to reuse a column that has been defined prior?

In real world, my prior `age` column is the result of a more complex calculation, and I want to reuse that value in an additional column in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define `age`and access it in the same step (this step being your select clause). You must do one thing after the other.

```
CREATE VIEW test AS 
  SELECT age, age AS person_age
  FROM (SELECT 30 AS age) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

in sql you can or repated  the code  ..  or use a view and select the alias

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT '30' AS age, '30' AS person_age;
```

or use a view and select the alias

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT '30' AS age; 


CREATE VIEW test2 AS SELECT age, age as person_age from test;
```